# Listing all queues binded to an exchange in RabbitMQ

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I am using amqllib in javascript and node.js
and I want to list all queues binded to a specific exchange .
what is the best wat to do that?

Comment: Best in terms of what exactly?

Comment: In terms of that it will work as fast as possible. I didnt find a function in the lib api that helps me with that.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the [HTTP API](https://cdn.rawgit.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/v3.7.6/priv/www/api/index.html) to do that.

Specifically, one or both of these endpoints:

```
/api/exchanges/vhost/name/bindings/source   A list of all bindings in which a given exchange is the source.
/api/exchanges/vhost/name/bindings/destination  A list of all bindings in which a given exchange is the destination.
```